# Is 「だれか素敵な人に...」 an example of apposition?

Tags: grammar

I found the following example sentence in "ドリル＆ドリル日本語能力試験N2文法" (p.49):

> 早く結婚したいなあ。だれか素敵な人に会えないかなあ。

My attempt at a translation would be:

> I want to get married soon! I wish I could meet someone nice.

My question is, are だれか and 素敵な人 in apposition here?

I don't think I've noticed apposition before in Japanese, so I'm wondering if I'm misinterpreting the grammar here.

Answer (score 2):

The Japanese language has appositive constructions, too, but I don't think だれか素敵な人 is an example of apposition. To say something is in apposition to something, you have to be able to join the two phrases using an equal sign (`=`) or "is".

- my friend Michael (Michael **is** my friend)
- Jack the Ripper (Jack **is** the ripper)
- アメリカ大統領ジョー・バイデン (Joe Biden **is** the US President)
- 水の都ヴェネツィア (Venice **is** the City of Water)

This does not apply for だれか素敵な人 ("someone is a nice person" is not correct). Likewise, I don't think "something delicious" or "someone special" in English is not an appositive construction.